# Open .lang file with python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Opening File

#### Files:

local_lexer.py
local_parser.py
main.py
test.lang


### Image

### main.py:

```
from local_lexer import Lexer
from local_parser import Parser

def main():

    # Read the currect flow source code in test.lang and store it in a variable
    content = ""
    with open('test.lang', 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()

    #
    # Lexer
    #

    # Calls the lexer class and initializes it with the source code
    lex = Lexer(content)
    # Make source code tokens
    tokens = lex.tokenize()

    #
    # Parser
    #

    parse = Parser(tokens)
    parse.parse()

main()
```

#### I want to double-click the "test.lang" file or drag the "test.lang" file on the main.py
and make it so the with open lines opens the file that previously had been dragged on the main.py

```
with open('file dragged', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
```

## How can I do this?
Thanks!

#### More Info:
Operating System: Windows

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: I'm on windows!

Comment: Files you drag end up in `sys.argv[1]`. You can get their names directly from there, or you can use `argparse` or another command-line parsing tool.

Comment: Note that it _is_ possible to have the Python interpreter's associations used by Windows Explorer get broken, but we do have existing, answered questions about how to fix it when that happens.